# Mongo balancer not migrating chunks based on Tags

Tags: mongodb

I have configured a two shard cluster and added the following tags.

```
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "mongo-db1:27018",  "tags" : [ "shard-product1" ] }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "mongo-db3:27018",  "tags" : [ "shard-product2" ] }

sh.addTagRange("mydb.products", { product : "product1", sno: MinKey}, {product : "product1", sno: MaxKey}, "shard-product1")

sh.addTagRange("mydb.products", { product : "product2", sno: MinKey}, {product : "product2", sno: MaxKey}, "shard-product2")
```

Here is the output of sh.status() for the given collection

```
 {  "_id" : "mydb",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    mydb.products
         shard key: { "product" : 1, "sno" : 1 }
              chunks:
                 shard0000       3
    { "product" : { "$minKey" : 1 }, "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "product" : "product1", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 1) 
    { "product" : "product1", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "product" : "product2", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 3) 
    { "product" : "product2", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "product" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }, "sno" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 4) 

    tag: shard-product1  { "product" : "product1", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "product" : "product1", "sno" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }
    tag: shard-product2  { "product" : "product2", "sno" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "product" : "product2", "sno" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }
```

When I add entries to products collection, all the entries (of both the products) are being added to the primary shard (shard-product1).

Is there any issue with the configuration above ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the balancer running? Check with `sh.getBalancerState()`. How much data is in the collection? Are "product1" and "product2" the only values for `product`?

Comment: sh.getBalancerState() returns false. Also i have read else where that the balancer is triggered only when chunk migration threshold is reached.I have tried to run the balancer manually using sh.startBalancer() but it does not have any effect.

Comment: @wdberkeley - 
product1, product2 are the only values for product. And all entries that i add are for product1, product2. The size of the data is 

     `code` { "count" : 41, "size" : 83312, "storageSize" : 172032 }`code`.
I also tried running the steps in this [post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672302/how-to-programatically-pre-split-a-guid-based-shard-key-with-mongodb), but could not do a pre-split. It seems like, I have a basic configuration issue. Is there any configuration option that i might be missing ?