# Mongodb cluster - importing billions of records

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongodb-cluster

I am trying to import 10 billion records. Started tested with importing 1 billion records. Import time getting worst as the records gets inserted. Here are configurations and stats.

```
Mongo db version - 3.4
Documents - 1226592923
Routers(m4.xlarge) 2 
Config 3
Nodes(i3.large,15GB nvme ssd)  Import time(hrs)
5                              14:30:00
10                             8:10:00
```

Each Document has around 7 fields. Shard key is on 3 fields. Followed all the recommendations at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings.

Import options

```
--writeConcern '{ w: 0, j: false }'
--numInsertionWorkers 8
```

Even tried disabling journal(`--nojournal`), but no much difference.

Not sure if this is the expected import time. Or is the way I can do anything else to improve ingestion rate?

Comment: Is the collection indexed?  What format is the data, and how was it created (mongoexport / mongodump)?

Comment: you may get some specific/better help over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you set up the splits on the shards before inserting the 10b docs?   Nice blog on the performance pik-up here: https://blog.zawodny.com/2011/03/06/mongodb-pre-splitting-for-faster-data-loading-and-importing/

Comment: @robjwilkins I tried both with and without indexing, but no much difference. Data is is json format, generated from spark

Comment: I agree with @BuzzMoschetti, you should definitly pre-split de the collection before starting your insertions. If you don't, the balancer will do it afterwards and it will take forever :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the factors made a lot of improvement in importing

1. Pre-splitting
2. Sorting data
3. Disabling the balancer `sh.stopBalancer()`
4. Turning off auto split during load(`sh.disableAutoSplit()` or restart the `mongos` without `--noAutoSplit`)
5. Indexing after loading complete data

**References:**

1. https://blog.zawodny.com/2011/03/06/mongodb-pre-splitting-for-faster-data-loading-and-importing/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672303